# How to create a sphere-shaped tile terrain using a for?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I initially apologize for my English, because I am from Brazil.

So I am creating a tile-generating terrain, but in this code below I create a square terrain, I would like to spheronize my terrain.

I would like to do something close to this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxzUc.jpg

```
List<Vector3> map = new List<Vector3>();
public List<Vector3> GenerateMap(int width, int height)
{

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
        {

            SpawnTile(new Vector3(x, 0, z ));
        }

    }

    return map;
}
```

I would like to do something close to this.

Comment: Spheres don't have `Width` and `Height`, they have a `CenterX`, `CenterY`, and `Radius` (or `Diameter`). Would that help here?

Comment: I'm kind of confused.